# Prototype's Ajax.Request and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

The following code is supposed to perform an AJAX request after the page loads, and then display the response of that AJAX call in a popup. This works in Firefox, but I have no idea why it does not work in IE8.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Do this stuff when DOM finishes loading.
        document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
            new Ajax.Request("page.html", {
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

page.html just contains

```
hello world
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this a result of the prototype js library not being fully compatible with IE8? I tried this with the latest stable prototype release (1.6.0.3) and the bleeding-edge version (1.6.1 RC3) with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this in a web site or using a file?  I was able to get your code working in a web site in Visual Studio, but when I tried it from a file I got an "Access Denied" error.  I suspect that it is not able to do an Ajax request to a file in the local file system due to security restrictions in IE8.

Here's the exact code I used in my Default.aspx page to load the page.htm file.  Note that I changed the method -- since it's not a form -- and I added callbacks for failure and exceptions.  The exception callback was what got triggered for me with a local file.  As I said, it works fine when accessing a page in the same web site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe( 'dom:loaded', function() {
        new Ajax.Request("page.htm", {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            onFailure: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            onException: function(request,error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an aside to the existing answer, and just wanted to mention, that IE8 does some crazy caching when you use 'get' in your Ajax calls. My web application worked fine in FF, but in IE8, some of the ajax calls were never made. I changed the method: from 'get' to 'post' and all was well.

```
method: 'post'
```

Also, to further ensure no funny business in IE8 with session variables, put the following meta tags in the head of your html pages.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Comment: Ah the memories of looking at this old answer. In my defense I did not have a good understanding of the restful concepts behind get vs post at the time.